Realization of coverings of complex plane with logarithmic branches
I am trying to understand branchings of Riemann surfaces. Consider $\mathbb{C}-\{z_1,z_2,z_3,...,z_k\}$. Consider branched covers of it such that at each point $z_i$ the covering at sheet $g$ is either not branching at all or has logarithmic type branching, i.e. behaves like $(z-z_i)^{\alpha_i}$ for irrational $\alpha_i$. There are no other singularities.
Question1: how to realize this cover by functions?
I.e., I would like to construct explicit functions $f_g(z)$, defined in vicinity of $z_i$ and satisfying some gluing conditions in the overlapping vicinities that behave like $f_g(z) = \sum f_{g,n} (z-z_i)^{\alpha_i+n}$ that realize the graph of this branched covering. Note that the expansion coefficients $f_{g,n}$ can depend on the sheet of analyticity.
Question2: How free we are in realizing the adjacent singularities on adjacent sheets of analiticity?
E.g, consider sheets $k=...-1,0,1,2, ...$ near $z_0$. Can we realize a covering that has $\alpha_1$ branches at $z_1$ on sheets, say, $-2,-1$ but is non branching on other sheets?
Geometric intuition tells me that there is no problem of realizing such coverings, but I would like to see explicit functional construction using the above Puiseux series.
Question3: How to construct the unimorfization of the above covering or at least differential equation that realizes it?
The covering is uniformized by the upper half plane. The covering is given by $z_i,\alpha_i$ and by the data on which sheets of analiticity, numbered by $g$, the branching is absent. It seems a bit tricky to describe explicitly over which group the index $g$ can run. It is some group with $k$ generators, but some branches are not realized so it is not the full free group. This is probably another question - how to describe this group explicitly.
